# How to call enum functions?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a following problem. I'm trying to implement a HashMap in java, but it has to be done on professor's terms. He wrote an outline of methods, and how they should look, so I can't change anything else beside write add(key, value) function from scratch.

```
public static enum HashingMethod {
        DivisionMethod,
        KnuthMethod
    };
```

DivisionMethod and KnuthMethod are both functions for hashing in a HashFunction class.
If somebody were to use this program, he would first create an instance of a HashMap class:
`HashMap hm = new HashMap(6, HashFunction.HashingMethod.DivisionMethod);`

and then use `hm.add(3, "Ambulance")` to add elements to it.

Here is the constructor for HashMap:

```
public HashMap(int m, HashFunction.HashingMethod h) {
        this.h = h;
        this.table = new LinkedList[m];
        for (int i=0; i<table.length; i++) {
            table[i] = new LinkedList<Element>();
        }
    }
```

What I would like to know is probably basic, but it's been keeping me from progressing for quite some time now.

**How do I know which hashing function has been selected, so I can use it in my `add(key, value)` method?**

Comment: In this case your best option is probably to actually include your hash function as a method of the enum. As an aside, please be aware of the naming conventions: enum constants should be all uppercase with `_` characters separating the words

Comment: Your HashMap implementation could have instance variable HashingMethod. Based on this variable you can make decision which hashing function will be used in your add(key, value) method. Please notice that put(key, value) is more appropriate - Map interface declares this method.

Comment: I am deleting my answer. Adding behavior to enums is simply bad practice. Enum's specs define them as constant values, a lot of frameworks treat them that way, So adding methods is just inviting trouble for when it is too late to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be storing the `HashingMethod` in a field called `h`.

To check the method selected do:

```
if (h == HashFunction.HashingMethod.DivisionMethod) {

    // use division method

}
```

etc.

Answer (score 4):

I would add an abstract method to the enum so there is no need of `if` or `switch`:

```
public static enum HashingMethod {
    DivisionMethod {
        @Override
        public int calcHash(Object o) {
            // do it
        }
    },
    KnuthMethod {
        @Override
        public int calcHash(Object o) {
            // do it
        }
    };

    public abstract int calcHash(Object o);
}
```

So you can invoke the enum-method directly

```
int bucket = this.h.calcHash(e);
```

Comment: If you read the specs/JVM enums are designed to be CONSTANT values. Adding behavior to them just makes things complicated. and when the problems hits you is too late to solve it efficiently.

Comment: Adding behaviour doesn't change the fact they're constant.  When used with care, it can be a very good tool.  Of course it is also often abused for translating constants from one domain or layer to another, linking those domains or layers in your enum implementation...

Comment: As described in [example 8.9.2-4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.2) it is 'is much safer than using a switch statement in the base type'.

Comment: Yes. *Effective Java* Item 30 has a similar example, plus more examples and discussion. Enum constants with behavior is clearly one of the intended uses of enums.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply switch over it:

```
switch(this.h) {
    case DivisionMethod: /*code*/; break;
    case KnuthMethod: /*code*/; break;
}
```